Typescript Type issu when pass an object through a component which is coming from database in Nextjs app at build time
[Help please] how can i solve the issue? there is an object called diary comming from an database and passed to component where a useState hook expecting that object. at build time it gives the following error.
[error showing in terminal at build time] (https://i.sstatic.net/JIlnQ2C9.png)
import { db } from "@/db";
import DiaryEditForm from "@/components/diary-edit-form";
interface DiaryEditPageProps {
    params: {
        id: string;
    };
}
export default async function DiaryEditPage(props: DiaryEditPageProps) {
        const id = parseInt(props.params.id);
        const diary = await db.diary.findFirst({
            where: { id },
            });
        return (
        <div>
        <DiaryEditForm diary={diary} />
        </div>
    );
}

"use client";

import { Diary } from "@prisma/client";
import { useState } from "react";
import * as actions from "@/actions";

interface DiaryEditFormProps {
  diary: Diary;
}
export default function DiaryEditForm({ diary }: DiaryEditFormProps) {
  const [content, setContent] = useState(diary);
  const handleEditorChange = (event: {
    target: { name: string; value: string };
  }) => {
    const { name, value } = event.target;
    setContent((prevContent) => ({
      ...prevContent,
      [name]: value,
    }));
  };
  const editDiaryAction = actions.editDiary.bind(
    null,
    diary.id,
    content.title,
    content.description
  );
  return (
    <form action={editDiaryAction} className="space-y-4">
      <h1 className="text-center font-semibold">Edit your Diary</h1>
      <div>
        <label
          htmlFor="title"
          className="block text-gray-700 font-medium mb-2 leading-tight"
        >
          Title
        </label>
        <input
          type="text"
          name="title"
          id="title"
          value={content.title}
          onChange={handleEditorChange}
          className="w-full px-3 py-2 border border-gray-300 rounded focus:outline-none focus:border-gray-500"
        />
      </div>
      <div>
        <label
          htmlFor="description"
          className="block text-gray-700 font-medium mb-2 leading-tight"
        >
          Description
        </label>
        <textarea
          name="description"
          id="description"
          value={content.description}
          onChange={handleEditorChange}
          className="min-h-32 w-full px-3 py-2 border border-gray-300 rounded focus:outline-none focus:border-gray-500"
        ></textarea>
      </div>

      <button
        type="submit"
        className="bg-gray-600 text-white px-4 py-2 rounded"
      >
        Save
      </button>
    </form>
  );
}

How can I solve this type error issu?

The error is telling you the types for diary do not match between what db.diary.findFirst and DiaryEditFormProps. For the page component, after getting the diary object, what should happen if the diary does not exist? You should add some logic to handle what the page should render if the diary doesn't exist. If you add this null handling check, the diary object will get narrowed down to Diary and you form component will receive what it expects.

thank you @moonstar-x. that's a easy solution I did not think that way... thanks again.

Your interface of Diary doesn't accept null value. And your api call which returns the data, will initially be null and hence you are getting the type error. Make a change here, to support nullable value:
interface DiaryEditFormProps {
    diary: Diary |null;
    }

